# How to create a json with different index?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using `Newwtonsoft.JSON` for build my json file, actually what I did is create different classes models, as this:

```
class GeneralModel
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

and then for build the json file:

```
GeneralModel lsModel = new GeneralModel();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lsModel);
File.WriteAllText(settingsFilePath, json);
```

this will create a json that contains `Language`, but I need to put in this json different classes, what I need is set an index that contains each class name, for example:

```
"GeneralModel": {
    "Language" : "english"
},
"AnoherClassName": {
    "ClassProperty" : value
}
```

how can I do this with Newtonsoft?

Comment: You show an Json array of objects. Try exactly the same in code - create an `object[]` array with the classes you want and serialize the array instead of individual objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class GeneralModel
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherModel
{
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SuperClass
{
    public GeneralModel generalModel { get; set; }

    public AnotherModel anotherModel { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
            SuperClass s = new WMITest.SuperClass();
            s.generalModel = new GeneralModel();
            s.generalModel.Language = "language";
            s.anotherModel = new AnotherModel();
              s.anotherModel.AnotherProperty = "example";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
```

Comment: is possible set another name instead of GeneralModel in the json without change the class name? I remember something like attribute